# PLC - PC communication using Snap7 in C# WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, plc

please, I have a question about snap7.dll library. So long time I wanst be working in C#, so maybe I am doing something wrong. But is possible to use snap7 in C# WPF project as library or it was developed only for windows forms? Its stupid I know, but I am asking because I am not able to add snap7.dll into my project references. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloaded and played around with the examples from http://snap7.sourceforge.net/
Looks like the console application doesn't reference the assembly directly.

This isn't a WPF vs Winforms thing. It is a managed vs unmanaged code thing.

There is a snap7.net.cs .net wrapper class file.
It references "snap7.dll" and exposes its functionality as a C# class. At runtime it will load the assembly using DllImport.

Copy both the snap7.net.cs file and the snap7.dll into your project.
Use the snap7 class methods/attributes in your code. Then update snap7.dll to copy to output directory, or use a post build event to copy the snap7.dll to your output directory.

EDIT: I want to restate you **do NOT add reference to the snap7.dll directly using project -> references**. The DllImport annotation of the wrapper class file will load it at runtime.